# R - Using input from my custom function to reference a dataframe column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, aggregate

Let's say that I have a dataframe called MYKVS

```
Subject HourNominal Concentration Cohort    FS    EF   VTI deltaFS deltaEF deltaVTI
  005-010        0.00            NA      1 30.87 65.48 21.59      0%      0%       0%
  005-010        0.25         31.00      1 31.82 64.86  0.00      3%     -1%    -100%
  005-010        1.00          9.69      1 26.13 69.11  0.00    -15%      6%    -100%
  005-010        3.00          3.26      1 29.89 60.99 23.49     -3%     -7%       9%
  005-010       24.00          1.52      1 29.67 57.18 22.17     -4%    -13%       3%
  005-010       48.00          1.23      1 35.41 56.70 20.85     15%    -13%      -3%
```

I have this function to aggregate this dataframe by HourNominal, and to find the mean of all Concentration values that fall on that time.

```
organizeR = function(x) {

  g1 = aggregate(MYKVS$x, by=list(MYKVS$HourNominal), FUN=mean)
  g1 = setNames(g1, c('HourNominal', 'Function'))

  return(g1)
}


CR1 = organizeR(FS)
```

Why does CR1 return

```
 Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate
```

If I input x, why can't I use the x input to reference a dataframe column inside my custom function?  Is this one of those weird parts of R?

Solution :

Thank you all for the tips.  As pointed out, the function should look like

```
organizeR = function(x) {

  g1 = aggregate(MYKVS[,x], by=list(MYKVS$HourNominal), FUN=mean)
  g1 = setNames(g1, c('HourNominal', 'Function'))

  return(g1)
}

CR1 = organizeR('FS')
```

Since R functions don't recognize objects unless pointed directly to an object name.

Comment: Maybe switch to `MYKVS[[x]]` and pass `FS` as `"FS"`.

Comment: in your function you will have to reference the MYKVS$x in aggregate to the actual name of the function. This might work `MYKVS[,x]` . Plus you'll have to change your function call to have your column name in quotes `CR1 = organizeR("FS")`

Comment: R does not understand FS (as its a column name in a dataframe) without knowing the data frame

Comment: sorry my comment above should actually read "reference the MYKVS$x in aggregate to the actual name of the *column*"